# Kia Soul - Humming Noise After Oil Change

Tags: kia

So last week I had my oil changed and immediately after picking up my car and turning it on I noticed that there was an audible "humming" sound coming from my car. I went back inside and told them about the issue but, supposedly, they could not find anything wrong with it. Color me skeptical.

Ever since then the car has had a low humming sound while in idle and while accelerating (at any type of acceleration - slow or fast acceleration) - I have noticed, though,  that the humming disappears when I go into neutral (the car is an automatic transmission).

Any ideas as what this might be? From what I've read it could be several things, but I didn't know if something, in particular, stuck out to somebody. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It doesn't go away while in park (sitting still), but does when you put it into neutral?

Comment: Have your transmission fluid level checked.

Comment: That's correct. When my car is in park there is the low humming sound but when I put it in neutral the sound goes away.